# JVM crashing when using AffineTransformOp to filter image

Tags: java, jvm, affinetransform

I have been wrestling with occassional JVM crashes when using [`AffineTransformOp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html) to filter image for a while now, and I was wondering if anyone can help me.  I have submitted a bug report to Oracle a while back [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7038635) and can't seem to get any response from them.  Has anyone dealt with these kinds of JVM crashes before?  Is there any workaround, or any way to catch these crashes?

Comment: Does any particular image fail reliably?

Comment: I don't see any image fail reliably.  I have seen during testing that rendering the same image over and over again can cause the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [failure](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7038635) occurs in the `transformBI()` method of [`sun.awt.image.ImagingLib`](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/awt/image/ImagingLib.java.html). As the method is native, the problem may be specific to one platform, OS version or image. I've not seen problems directly attributable to [`AffineTransformOp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html), but thread-related problems are common. It may be helpful to verify that all GUI objects are created and manipulated only on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: Since the crash occurs inconsistently and it can occur by just opening and closing the same image over and over again, I think it is a threading issue.  This code is called from paint(Graphics g) which I thought by definition occurs on the event dispatch thread, is this not the case?

Comment: No, use [`isDispatchThread()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) to see; use [`invokeLater()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style#Continuations_as_objects) as required.

Comment: If this is Swing, "programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding paint()."—[The Paint Methods](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try upgrading to Java 7? It says they've accepted it as a low priority bug -- that's probably all the response you should expect until they fix it. Or maybe you could switch platforms (to Linux for example) since the bug seems to be in the native code.

Comment: I thought that if they had fixed the bug in Java 7 then they would have updated the ticket.  Is that not the case?

Comment: Try 1.6.0_17 instead of 1.6.0_24. Chances are it is a regression and is not present in earlier releases.

Comment: Could you tell me where you got this from?  I'm interested in reading about it.  Thanks

Comment: @Jon -- It doesn't hurt to try right? Perhaps they didn't "fix it" per se but maybe it never existed in Java 7 due to code rewrites, different internal design, etc. Also, as a last resort you could then try an older version in case it was a regression.